# Options for displaying 3D data using ESRI web APIs

Tags: web-mapping, 3d, arcgis-platform

I've been looking through the documentation of the various ESRI web APIs to see if there is any support for displaying 3D data, but haven't found anything useful. Is there any support for this - or do any other web APIs (Google, Bing, OpenLayers, etc) offer anything extra?

I'm assuming what's on offer is probably quite limited considering the need to purchase ArcGIS 3D Analyst for the desktop side of things.

I'm interesting in displaying either raster or vector data - or ideally both if that's possible. Any examples of what is possible would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this link on ArcGIS 10.

It's about managing 3D virtual city data and has a lot of useful information. It can use ArcGIS explorer API as well as 3D Analyst.

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/creating_managing_and_utilizing_a_3d_virtual_city_in_arcgis_10.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at City Engine:
http://www.esri.com/software/cityengine

There are several samples in http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=CityEngine&title=CityEngine%20Web%20Scenes